# Can $argv be forged from php get?

Tags: php, security

Question: is there any way to forge `$argv` values from a get request?

Background:

I wrote a simple php script that I would like to be accessible from either the command line or via a get request.  If it is used via command line, I can call the script called as such `php myScript.php variableValue`.  It currently works great like this.  However when calling from the internet, I need a security code as well. Using this pseudocode, these would be the values in the `$_GET` array.

```
$_GET["variableValue"]="abcde";
$_GET["securityCode"]="IjfkeLEkf738J9("`
```

To figure out where the script is called from, I just check to see the length of `$argv` array.  If it has more than 1 element, I evaluate it with the $argv value.  Otherwise I evaluate with the `$_GET` value.  If I evaluate with the $argv value, I don't check the securityCode, hence my question as to whether $argv can be forged from a get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, **but**.  On newer versions of PHP it shouldn't be an issue.  On older versions, as long as `register_globals` is off, the GET vars will not be automatically converted to global variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect whether the script is being called from the command line by either inspecting the [`PHP_SAPI`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#reserved.constants.core) constant or using the [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) function. Example:

```
if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
     $variableValue = $_GET["variableValue"];
     $securityCode = $_GET["securityCode"];
     // check the above values and deny access if they are not the right ones.
}
```

Comment: I upvoted you because this looks like the best way to do it, but I marked GrandmasterB as correct because it is a more direct answer to the question's title.